# Is there a way to add a 0 in the corner of a multiplication table

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def multiply(end):
    pro = ""
    for i in range(end + 1):
        for j in range(end + 1):
            pro += str(i * j) + "\t"
        pro += "\n"
    return pro
```

When I run my code it returns when I call the function multiply(4):

```
0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   2   3   4   
0   2   4   6   8   
0   3   6   9   12  
0   4   8   12  16
```

I want it to return as:

```
0   1   2   3   4   
1   1   2   3   4   
2   2   4   6   8   
3   3   6   9   12  
4   4   8   12  16
```

What do I have to change and I also need to return the table instead of printing the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a few checks to your function but this should work -

```
def multiply(end):
    pro = ""
    for i in range(0,end + 1):
        for j in range(0,end + 1):
            if i != 0 and j != 0:
                pro += str(i * j) + "\t"
            else:
                pro += str(max(j,i)) + "\t"
        pro += "\n"
    return pro
```

with this `multuply(4)` has an output of -

```
0       1       2       3       4
1       1       2       3       4
2       2       4       6       8
3       3       6       9       12
4       4       8       12      16
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I don't understand what the code in the else statement do and why it works can you explain?

Comment: Sure. The reason you get 0's in the outer rows and columns is because  `i` or `j` is 0, the `if` checks for these cases. The `max()` function gives the larger of two given numbers, I used it to replace the 0 values with is basically the index for that position. Please don't forget to accept my answer as it helped you out.

Answer (score -1):

range(x) gives a list from 0 to x-1. Try range(1,x).

```
def multiply(end):
    pro = ""
    for i in range(1,end + 1):
        for j in range(1,end + 1):
            pro += str(i * j) + "\t"
        pro += "\n"
    return pro
```